# How can I access a user entered string (from a Rails form) inside of a Ruby model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently struggling with the rails implementation of an application I wrote in Ruby.

**Background:**

I am trying to use the Soundcloud API to request a artist's properties based on an artist URL entered by a user inside a rails form. The code that makes the request to the Soundcloud API is inside of two ruby models in my services folder (app/services/soundcloud_query.rb). What I require is the dynamic setting of a variable named `@user_url` equal to the soundcloud artist URL that the user is interested in.

I have this all working on the command line where I can use the Ruby gets command to get the user input, however, I am struggling to understand how to implement this properly in the rails framework. My query logic is all fine, it is simply the handing of information from a user field to the model that I am struggling with.

**Example of expected behaviour:**

I have a rails form with one text field. The user is prompted to enter a Soundcloud artist URL inside (example: https://soundcloud.com/alembicmusic ). I then want to take this string, set it equal to the `@user_url` property in my `soundcloud_query.rb` model, and then make the query based on a user entered URL. It is this middle part, where I run the code in my service model AFTER it gets a user input that I am struggling with.

I greatly appreciate any help/tips/resources and thank you for your time in reading this.

**Controller:**

```
class SimplePagesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @user = SoundcloudUser.new
    @followers= @user.followers
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in a nutshell, you want to know how to grab the form param values once the user "submits" it to the Rails server?

You can access data sent to a rails controller via the **params** hash, which is a key value pairing.

```
def find_artist
    # {"user_url":"www.soudcloud.com/pantera"}
    artist_url = params[:user_url]
    # do something with it from here on
end
```

The thing to note here is that your form should be routing to some sort of method in the controller which won't be your index method. 
I would suggest giving this a go if you're struggling with the Rails framework: https://www.railstutorial.org/book

Comment: Thanks JayJay, yeah I realized I am struggling with some fundamental stuff here, so will close this question and go back to the basics of MVC communication. The params hash is a very good tip as I do remember using this before. Thanks!